# What is wrong with this code I can't create simple UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
UIImage * imageSetting= [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting-button"];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageSetting];
self.editSettings = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:imageView];
PO(self.editSettings);
```

In Addition:

```
self.editSettings = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
PO(self.editSettings);
```

In both cases self.editSettings return null.

So, PO(self.editSettings) return null

Comment: Can't see you adding the button anywhere(?)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Has the view been created using the Interface builder? Are you adding the editSettings to the View after you have assigned it with the new instance?

Comment: I forget to mention that self.editSettings is null. That's how I know that things go wrong.

Comment: editSettings being a property of the class UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show this in the question but this behaviour could be explained by `editSettings` being a weak property. If you assign directly to a weak property from an initialisation, ARC will remove the object since nothing has a strong pointer to it.

Either use a local variable to create the bar button item, then make sure you add it to a toolbar or navigation bar before it goes out of scope, or change the property to strong.

Comment: bingo that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because of this?:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-button"];
```

You (for some reason) do not specify the file-extension. (.png most likely)*. 
If the file "settings-button" does not exist, the UIImage *imageSettings will be nil.

This will in turn make the initWithImage: fail (as there is no image) and finally initWithCustomView:nil will also return nil...

Edit:
***As Martin states below the extension isn't necessary if it is png so for my answer to be correct it has to either be a typo in the actual file-name or another file-type than .png.**

Comment: As of iOS4 and above it is not necessary to include the extension.

Comment: Didn't know that. How does the compiler handle this if you have a jpg and png with the same name then?

Comment: Ok i wasnt exactly correct. Here is the reference from the documentation `Special Considerations
On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.`